# Service worker no longer works as expected in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps

So again like other thousand times I updated my service workers file version, to check any errors, I opened the Chrome(Browser) developer tool, and what I see... fetching works in a new way...ERROR?
`Fetch finished loading: GET "https://www.example.com/favicon.ico". etc...some more CSS and image, I don't know what this is: Fetch failed loading: GET "https://www.example.com/".` (the last line of console log)

Why it needs to request the domain top root every time...
Now I check the headers (DEV tools - Network - Headers) because the network status = `(failed)`

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/
Referrer Policy: unsafe-url
```

pretty much no headers info at all or any content???

If I use the preload it shows extra ERROR in red `(The service worker navigation preload request failed with network error:net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED)`, so I have disabled preload for now, the service worker would still work with this error.

I had just updated to PHP 8.0 so maybe that was doing something, but after getting back to the old version nothing changed. Maybe my server started blocking some sort of requests, but that is unlikely, more like bad request from chrome service workers.

If the Chrome tries to check with the last request some sort of offline capacity, I use to display an offline page if fetch error, If that has anything to do with this.

Anyways despite the problems/errors described above the service worker works like it should.

Anyways, here is the SW code example:

```
    const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
var filevers='xxxx';
const CACHE_NAME = 'offline'+filevers;
// Customize this with a different URL if needed.
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offlineurl.php';
const OFFLINE_URL_ALL = [
  'stylesheet'+filevers+'.css',
  'offlineurl.php',
  'favicon.ico',
  'img/logo.png'
].map(url => new Request(url, {credentials: 'include'}));
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request will ensure that the response
    // isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be from the network.
  await cache.addAll(OFFLINE_URL_ALL);
  })());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    // Enable navigation preload if it's supported.
    // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
//removed for now
  })());

  // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // We only want to call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
  // for an HTML page.
            const destination = event.request.destination;
if (destination == "style" ||  destination == "script" ||  destination == "document" ||  destination == "image" ||  destination == "font") {    
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      try {
           const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
         if (cachedResponse) {
             return cachedResponse;
             } else {
        // First, try to use the navigation preload response if it's supported.
//removed for now
                const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
        return networkResponse;
         
        } 

      } catch (error) {
           if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
        // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is likely
        // due to a network error.
        // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
        // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.

        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
        return cachedResponse;
        }
      }
    })());
}

});
```

Any suggestions, what may cause the error?

Comment: if I add the './' to the URL list, it does not show any error fetching, but once I add the preload functionality the main www.example.com URL fails to load, it shows (canceled) now with the network error.

Comment: Anyways, this './'  is not a solution because I do not want to cache my front page. Is this a new criteria of Chrome you must cache your front page?

Comment: Yes that is it: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/improved-pwa-offline-detection/